# Use variable of one function in another (Three.js) Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, three.js, scope, global-variables

I had loaded an obj file using three.js
I tried acquring its vertex 'X' position and save it in 'pos' inside the objloader function which is in the init() function. 
I want to use the variable's value in another function say displayposition()
when I try

```js
var pos;

function init() {
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.load('objectfile.obj', function(object) {
        scene.add(object);
        pos = scene.children[5].children[0].geometry.attributes.position.getX(0);
        console.log(pos); //This displays the vertex position value
    });
}

function displaypos() {
    console.log(pos); //It doesn't display the vertex position value
}
```

How to make it global and make the  variable value of 'pos' usable throughout the  program..

Comment: When you assign pos into the callback, you have not to re-declare. You should replace `var pos = scene...` with `pos = scene...`. If you declare it the `pos` inside the callback will be a completely different variable from global `pos`, just with the same name.

Comment: I removed the var re-declaration still it doesn't display the  value..

Comment: Did you check that the callback was called before than  `displaypos` method?

Comment: yes  first i called init(); then continued by displaypos();

Comment: Ok, but did you verify that is called also the callback? The one you pass to `objLoader.load` method. Also, I suggest to improve indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OBJLoader.load` is an asynchronous function that downloads and parses the OBJ file. This may take no time at all, or it may take several seconds.

You say you are calling `init` followed immediately by `displaypos`. These function calls are sequential, so `displaypos` will be called *immediately after* `init` exits.

The order of operations here goes:

1. Create the global variable `pos`
2. Define the `init` function
3. Define the `displaypos` function
4. Call `init`

   1. Define `objloader` as a `THREE.OBJLoader`
   2. Define the callback for `objLoader.load`
   3. Call `objLoader.load` **<-- This is asynchronous and may take some time**
   4. `init` exits *because the call to `objloader.load` was sequential with a callback*
5. Call `displaypos`

   1. Print `undefined` to the console

*A few seconds later...*

1. The callback for `objloader.load` is called

   1. Add `object` to `scene`
   2. Set the value of `pos`
   3. `console.log` prints the correct value to the console

So your `displaypos` call isn't printing the the value because there is no value to print... yet.

You can add your own callback to `init` to make this work how you expect, or you can re-write your code to use [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) + [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

### Callback version

```js
var pos;

function init(callback) {
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.load('objectfile.obj', function(object) {
        scene.add(object);
        pos = scene.children[5].children[0].geometry.attributes.position.getX(0);
        console.log(pos); //This displays the vertex position value
        callback(); // The real exit point
    });
}

function displaypos() {
    console.log(pos);
}

init(function(){
    displaypos(); // will now display the correct value
});

// alternately: init(displaypos);
```

### Promise + async/await

```js
var pos;

async function init() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){

        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.load('objectfile.obj', function(object) {
            scene.add(object);
            pos = scene.children[5].children[0].geometry.attributes.position.getX(0);
            console.log(pos); //This displays the vertex position value
            resolve(); // the real exit point
        });

    });
}

function displaypos() {
    console.log(pos);
}

(async function(){
    await init();
    displaypos(); // will display the correct value
})();
```

Comment: Thankyou so much that worked..Great answer and great explanation ..But is there a way I can use the pos as a global variable without using callback or promise functions..And also if I want to get console.log(pos) after loader function but still within the init() function I still get undefined .Is there a way to get that pos within the same functions other functions also..Like I want a global declaration..

Comment: @PopupDev No. You are expecting to use the variable (which _is_ global) in a synchronous manner, but you are assigning its value within an asynchronous context. I recommend you do some reading on how synchronous vs. asynchronous operations work in JavaScript. [Here's a good starting point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous), and you can find more on the web.